# How can these two lines from Mahopanishad be reconciled?

Tags: advaita

[**SOURCE**](http://www.advaita.it/library/mahaupanishad.htm)

> I-1-4. Then we shall expound the Mahopanishad. They say Narayana was alone. There were not Brahma, Shiva, Waters, Fire and Soma, Heaven and Earth, Stars, Sun and Moon. He could not be happy.

This line is absolutely foundational for the doctrine of Hari-Sarvottamatvam for  Madhwites and Srivaishnavites.

But

> V-113. ‘He who cherishes with the (creative) and liberating imagination (the thought that) all this is spirit, that the perception of difference is nescience, should renounce this (nescience) in all possible ways.

Which is purely advaitic, - proclaiming Jeeva-Brahman identity.

Have Vaishnavite teachers explained this?